# Why is Kafka Consumer's Performance with latest offset and earliest offset different?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

The fetch request is the same.

```
maxWait: 100ms
minBytes: 1
fetchSize: 1048576
```

When I consume from the earliest offset, it's very fast and can be 10,000 records per second. However, when I consume from the latest offset, it's very slow and can be 10,000 records per minute.

Anyone knows why?

Comment: Do you reset your cluster between runs? Which version are you using? Which tool are you using to measure performance?

Comment: How much data do you _write_ into the topic? If you process from the end of the topic (ie, "latest"), you will only process data that is written by a producer into the topic at the same time. If the producer only writes 10000 per minute, you process everything there is.

Answer (score 1):

In the `earliest` mode, Kafka has data stored on the disk and in every fetching data it can fetch 1048576KB of data (untill reading all the data on the disk), but in the `latest` mode Kafka listen for new data and it also depends on the producer rate of data generation. In the `latest` mode Kafka will wait `maxWate` and received all new data. So it's a natural behavior.